# Pass class state to functional component (typescript)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-component, react-functional-component

I have a `Company.tsx` component and I am using a functional component `ControlledOpenSelect` inside it as shown below.

How can I pass `state` of `Company` component to the functional component?

I tried using the following:

```
<ControlledOpenSelect dataforDownload = {this.state.selectedAsset}/>
```

where, `selectedAsset` is an object like this:

`Object { id: 223, assetsTypeId: 11, fileName: "cdd_p_ABC_B43B170A4181.zip", locationTypeId: 1, path: null, fullPathName: "/mnt/nfs/Data/prod/downloader/XYZ/cdd_p_XYZ_B43B909CAC170A4181.zip", ownerId: 12354, … }`

But I keep on getting following error:

```
Type '{ dataforDownload: []; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.
  Property 'dataforDownload' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.ts(2322)
```

**Code from `Company` component:**

My `selectedAsset` is defined like this in my `Company.tsx` file
`selectedAsset: []`,

```
export interface CompanyState extends IGridProps {

addIntendedUseVisible:boolean,
selectedAsset: []

}
 
handleCancel = (e) => {
    this.setState({  addIntendedUseVisible: false, selectedAsset: [] },   () => {
        //this.fetchRecords()
    })
}  
 
handleOk = (values) => {
    
     axios.post(`api/company/${values.id}`, {
            
        }).then((response) => {
           this.setState({
                addIntendedUseVisible: false,
                selectedAsset: []
           }
 }  

handleDownloadClick = (data, e) => {

    console.log("Date Object Test inside handleDownloadClick");
    console.log(data);

    
        this.setState({
            selectedAsset: data,
            addIntendedUseVisible: true
        })
  
  
}

public render() {

  const addDownloadDialog = this.state.addIntendedUseVisible ? (
            <Dialog visible={true} modal={true} className="add-download-popup"
                    onHide={() => this.setState({addIntendedUseVisible: false})}>
                <div style={{textAlign: 'center'}}>
                    <h5>Intended Use Dialog</h5>
                    <ControlledOpenSelect dataforDownload = {this.state.selectedAsset} handleCancel={this.handleCancel} handleOk={this.handleOk} />
                   
                </div>
            </Dialog>
        ) : null


    
    return (
            <div>
                //some other stuff
                {addDeleteDialog}

                //some other stuff
            </div>
        );
```

**My `ControlledOpenSelect` functional component is as follows:**

```
import { makeStyles, Theme, createStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import InputLabel from '@material-ui/core/InputLabel';
import MenuItem from '@material-ui/core/MenuItem';
import FormControl from '@material-ui/core/FormControl';
import Select from '@material-ui/core/Select';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) =>
  createStyles({
    button: {
      display: 'block',
      marginTop: theme.spacing(2),
    },
    formControl: {
      margin: theme.spacing(1),
      minWidth: 120,
    },
  }),
);

export default function ControlledOpenSelect() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  
  const [age, setAge] = React.useState('');
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

 
  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setAge(event.target.value);   
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  const handleOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Button className={classes.button} onClick={handleOpen}>
        Open the select
      </Button>
      <FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
        <InputLabel id="demo-controlled-open-select-label">Age</InputLabel>
        <Select
          labelId="demo-controlled-open-select-label"
          id="demo-controlled-open-select"
          open={open}
          onClose={handleClose}
          onOpen={handleOpen}
          value={age}
          onChange={handleChange}
        >
          <MenuItem value="">
            <em>None</em>
          </MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
      <Button size="small" variant="contained" color="primary" style={{marginTop: '40px'}} type="button" >OK</Button>
      <Button size="small" variant="contained" color="primary"style={{marginTop: '40px'}} type="button" onClick={handleCancel} >Cancel</Button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: What sort of thing is `selectedAsset`? Can you precisely describe its type?

Comment: It's an Object. Let me know if I need to clarify more. Thanks !

Comment: Can you describe the type of the object? Properties, sorts of values, etc? That's what's needed for the code to work

Comment: It's like this `Object { id: 223, assetsTypeId: 11, fileName: "cdd_p_ABC_B43B170A4181.zip", locationTypeId: 1, path: null, fullPathName: "/mnt/nfs/Data/prod/downloader/XYZ/cdd_p_XYZ_B43B909CAC170A4181.zip", ownerId: 12354, … }` Please let me know if I can clarify more. Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `ControlledOpenSelect` to be defined in such a way that it takes a `dataforDownload` prop of the type you need:

```
type DataforDownload = {
  id: number;
  assetsTypeId: number;
  fileName: string;
  locationTypeId: number;
  path: null; // ?
  fullPathName: string;
  ownerId: number;
  // and whatever other properties it has
};
export default function ControlledOpenSelect({ dataForDownload }: { dataforDownload: DataforDownload }) {
```

Then you can pass `dataforDownload` down to `ControlledOpenSelect` and use it inside.

Comment: I see. And my `ControlledOpenSelect` is not a `tsx` file but `jsx`. So it's still going to be like the way you mentioned? starting from `type DataforDownload = { ` etc ? Thanks !

Comment: If it's not in TypeScript, then either turn it into a TypeScript file and use the type like that, or `declare` its existence and its shape outside in TypeScript somewhere. You need TypeScript to recognize the component's shape.

Comment: I am getting this error after making changes and converting the js file to tsx file in my `Company` component. Here is the screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FzhK6.png

Comment: Sounds like the `selectedAsset` value in state is not typed properly as a `DataForDownload` - check how your state is defined, and make sure TypeScript can recognize the type of `selectedAsset` properly.

Comment: My `selectedAsset` is defined like this in my `Company.tsx` file 
`selectedAsset: []`. I updated my code to include more info. Does this means that I need to change how we have defined `type DataforDownload = {` in `ControlledOpenSelect.tsx`? 2) Also, once this works how can I access individual values inside the `export default function ControlledOpenSelect({ dataForDownload }: { dataforDownload: DataforDownload }) {` Thanks !

Comment: Despite that error, when I tested it like this inside `ControlledOpenSelect.tsx` - ` console.log("Testing dataforDownload function inside ControlledOpenSelect");
  console.log(dataforDownload);`, I saw my object there.

Comment: Wait, is it an array, or an object? You should define it so that it has the `DataforDownload` type required, rather than the type of an empty array that it is currently. Eg `selectedAsset: [] as Array<DataforDownload>` or `selectedAsset: null as (null | DataforDownload)` if you assign an object to it later

Comment: The JavaScript can run fine if you ignore TypeScript errors - the only problem you're having is getting TypeScript to accept your code, since your code isn't typed properly at the moment.

Comment: Quick question - if I have to pass a function here `<ControlledOpenSelect dataforDownload = {this.state.selectedAsset}/>`, I would do it like this `<ControlledOpenSelect dataforDownload = {this.state.selectedAsset} handleCancel={this.handleCancel}/>`, how can I make sure that it's acceptable in `ControlledOpenSelect.tsx` ? I am wondering just like we handled `dataforDownload`, how can we handle the function so that I could state the state of parent from the child. Thanks !

Comment: If `handleCancel` doesn't take any parameters, it'd be typed as: `handleCancel: () => void`, or with a string parameter, for example: `handleCancel: (param: string) => void`

Comment: I updated my code with this function. So if I want to call this when cancel button is clicked, I would just defined it like `handleCancel: () => void` below the `type DataforDownload = {` block?

Comment: If you want to define it on its own line, it'd need to be a `type`: `type HandleCancel = () => void` Or declare it inline: `({ dataForDownload, handleCancel }: { dataforDownload: DataforDownload, handleCancel: () => void }`

Comment: Sorry to bug you again. One last question. I have added a scenario of `handleOk` function as well in my post.So, when a user click on `Ok` button inside `ControlledOpenSelect` component, I want to send `dataforDownload` object and `purpose` parameter from the `ControlledOpenSelect` back to the `Company` component's `handleOk` function. Can I define the it like this `<Button size="small" variant="contained" color="primary" style={{marginTop: '40px'}} type="button" onClick= {(e) =>handleOk(dataForDownload,purpose)} >OK</Button>` inside `ControlledOpenSelect` ?